# Why an extra iteration on the first feature of a GeoJSON layer?

Tags: python, gdal, geojson

I'm using Python and GDAL to iterate over the features in a GeoJSON layer and I'm seeing this strange behavior where the first iteration is repeated a second time before moving onto the next feature.

**I only observe this when:**
- opening the vector with `gdal.GA_Update` option
- including a `layer.SetFeature()` within the loop
- `gdal` version 2.4.1 (not observed in 2.2.4)

This example shows there is only 1 feature, but the print statement within the loop is called twice and prints FID 0 both times. With a GeoJSON containing more features, I observed that only the first feature iteration is repeated twice.

```
from osgeo import gdal

vector_path = 'test.geojson'

with open(vector_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write('{"type": "FeatureCollection", "name": "test", "features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "foo": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -1, -1 ], [ -1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, -1 ], [ -1, -1 ] ] ] } }]}')

vector = gdal.OpenEx(vector_path, gdal.OF_VECTOR | gdal.GA_Update)
layer = vector.GetLayer()

print(layer.GetFeatureCount())

for feature in layer:
    print(feature.GetFID())
    layer.SetFeature(feature)

layer = None
vector = None
```

Is there something wrong with my GeoJSON file? Or with the GeoJSON driver?

Comment: Try not mutating `layer` when you're iterating over it, and see if the issue persists. i.e. don't do `layer.SetFeature(feature)`.

Comment: The issue does not appear without the `SetFeature()`, but it also does not appear for other vector formats *with* the `SetFeature()`

Comment: I'd suggest it's a bug.  Modifying a feature while iterating is a common use case (i.e ArcGIS's `UpdateCursor`).  Perhaps raise this on the GDAL-DEV mailing list.

Comment: Possibly related to commit [bd668db - GeoJSON: speed-up random reading with GetFeature() by storing a map FID->(start,size) to retrieve performance similar to GDAL 2.2 or before](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/bd668db37eb6f176226ebbe7efe34cfac86a3cf6#diff-9a29bbc20a853d9a45f8122b9b80f466)

Comment: It may indeed be a bug, but it's generally not a good practice to mutate something while iterating over it.

Comment: @RichardLaw I don't believe it is poor practice.  It's a common and supported practice (inc. update cursors in RDBMS as well as geospatial software),  Mutating the iterator itself on the other hand is bad and has caused me grief because of subtle bugs before.

Comment: @davemfish you can modifyeach [feature](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Feature-class.html) directly, without having to use SetFeature to replace it.

Comment: I suggest to ask this from the gdal-dev mailing list.

Comment: @user2856 `layer.setFeature` *is* mutating the iterator, that's what I'm arguing is a bad practice.

Comment: No it's meant to overwrite the feature, which *shouldn't* affect the iterator. That it does, is a bug not a practice.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's interest. Here's the resolution: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1687

Comment: @user2856 maybe we just to have agree to disagree. I didn't read the `layer.setFeature` source, but using any method of `layer` while iterating over `layer` is a code smell to me.